# flash components and resizing

Tags: actionscript-3, components, flash, resize

I am trying to create a chat program using Flash AS3, and so far, everything is going well, except for when the window is resized, my components are going to cut. I've used:

```
stage.align = "TL";
stage.scaleMode = "noScale";
```

Comment: it looks like the question is truncated.

Comment: Can you give solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
import flash.display.StageAlign;
import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

...

public function InitializeChatProgram() 
{
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to resize your objects properly, you need to rearrange them when the size of the window changes. For instance, if your chat component must be horizontally centered, your code would like :

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeHandler);

private function resizeHandler(event:Event):void {
   component.x = (stage.stageWidth+component.width) / 2;
}
```

If don't want to rearrange them and scale them proportionally, try to set the stage scale mode to other `StageScaleMode` values.